# Translation Transformation on the Invariant Interval (Spacetime)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, poincare-symmetry

So we know that the invariant interval in a two-dimensional spacetime in special relativity is given by

$$ s = -c^2t^2 + x^2 = -c^{'2}t^{'2} + x^{'2}$$

So this scalar should hold true in all frames. I'm trying to show that it is true under a spatial translation, but am not sure how to start.

I tried letting $x' \rightarrow x+\triangle x $. But am not sure how to continue from here. Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: The invariant interval is $\Delta s^2 = - c^2 (t_2 - t_1)^2 + (x_2 - x_1)^2$, not what you have written. Translational invariance is then the statement that if $(t_1,x_1) \to (t_1+a_1,x_1+a_2)$ and $(t_2,x_2) \to (t_2+a_1,x_2+a_2)$ then $\Delta s^2 \to \Delta s^2$.

Comment: Please note that Physics.StackExchange is not a homework help site. Please read [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093).

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is interested, I figured it out. 
Consider a 2D spacetime

$$\triangle s^2= -c^2(t_2 -t_1)^2 + (x_2 - x_1)^2 $$

A translation would mean $ x_1 \rightarrow x_1+x_0 $.

Now we go back to the unprimed frame and consider a 2-vector $\textbf{A}_i = (t_i,x_i) $. Let me also set c = 1.

To get the difference, $$\textbf{A}_2 - \textbf{A}_1 = (t_2-t_1,x_2-x_1)$$

Going to the primed frame would give 
$$\textbf{A}'_2 - \textbf{A}'_1 = (t_2-t_1,(x_2+x_0)-(x_1+x_0))$$
$$ =  (t_2-t_1,x_2-x_1)$$

Therefore if we take the square of it,
$$\triangle s^2 = \triangle s'^2$$

edit: didnt notice prahar's comment but yeah! thanks for pointing out my (mis)notation.